# floating div using jQuery()

Tags: jquery, css

hello friends i designed a floating div and its working perfectly but due to some reasons i don't want to use `position:relative` or `position:absolute` in my code

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

        var topWindowPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        var leftWindowPosition = $(window).scrollLeft();
        var topLeftNavHeight = 200;
        if (topWindowPosition >= topLeftNavHeight) {
            $("#scroll").css({ top: topWindowPosition - topLeftNavHeight, left: 0, position: 'relative' });
        } else {
            $("#scroll").css({ top: 0, left: 0, position: 'relative' });
        }
        $("#scroll").forceRedraw();
    });
```

you can also see working demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/9E225/1/

can i make the same effect without using positions please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use `margins` instead of `positions`. Eg:

```
if (topWindowPosition >= topLeftNavHeight) {
    $("#scroll").css({ marginTop: topWindowPosition - topLeftNavHeight, marginLeft: 0});
} else {
    $("#scroll").css({ marginTop: 0, marginLeft: 0 });
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9E225/2/

Comment: I would have posted the same. `marginLeft` is not really needed, though.

Comment: Haha I just edited the existing jsFiddle, not sure if he's got some other use for it. If not, then @Kamal you can remove the marginLeft :)

Comment: Thank u so much u r a life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you feel about this approach. It snaps the element into place when it goes beyond the scroller element, and snaps right back when it goes back. The main advantage to this approach is that your `#scroll` element won't be "jumping" back and repositioning itself on every scroll event fired.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PtmWe/) | Code

```
var $el = $("#scroll");
var original_top = $el.position().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    //Scrolled past element
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= original_top){
        //Add hooked element, if it's not already hooked
        if(!$el.hasClass("hooked")) $el.addClass("hooked");
    }else if($(window).scrollTop() <= original_top){
        //Scrolled up before element, remove hooking and return back to normal
        if($el.hasClass("hooked")) $el.removeClass("hooked");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.hooked{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Also, I'd recommend taking a look at [this "JQuery Waypoints" library](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). It operates in the same way as the above code, but has much more functionality. :)